# International Certificate of Vaccination

Tags: health, switzerland

Where can I exchange my local (Swiss) certificate of vaccination with an international one? Is it possible?

Comment: You will get it from the local health authority in Switzerland. Just ask the hospital or authority that issued your certificate. The international one is in the form of a yellow card.

Comment: I do have both, an international and Swiss one but want to transfer all entry from the Swiss one to the international one.

Comment: I believe the international one is only for certain diseases.

Comment: Realistically the international certificate generally only serves a single purpose - to show that you have had a Yellow Fever inoculation. Having any other vaccinations listed on it serves little to no purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have both certificates of vaccination from birth and all my vaccinations were put into both certificates. If you want to transfer the vaccinations from one to the other it has to be done by any physician. In Switzerland, I would visit my family physician for that.

just FYI: you can also use a electronic certificate of vaccinations, I don't know if you can use it abroad tough: [Government website](https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/de/home/service/publikationen/broschueren/publikationen-uebertragbare-krankheiten/schweizerischer-elektronischer-impfausweis.html)